# Troubleshooting GWPR/PLM duplicate couples error

Tags: r, gis, plm

I am trying to run a Geographically weighted panel regression model as seen below.
However I keep on getting an error of duplicate ids.

```
     bw.GWPR(formula = formula1, data = finalprepostdataset3,
                    SDF = finalprepostdataset_sp,
                    index = c("county_id", "season"),
                    adaptive = TRUE, approach = "AIC",
                    p = 2, effect = "twoways", model = "within",
                    doParallel=T, cluster.number=4,
                    kernel = "bisquare", longlat = FALSE, bigdata = T)
Error in { : task 1 failed - "duplicate couples (id-time)
```

`finalprepostdataset_sp` is a spatial copy of `finalprepostdataset3`. I read guides to get rid of this problem (my understanding is that it derives from the way `plm` handles panel data) but I still am getting errors. To be clearer, I can run this code successfully:

```
plm(
  formula=formula1,
  data=finalprepostdataset3,
  effect = "time",
  model = "within",
  index = c("county_id", "season"),
)
```

And:

```
any(table(index(finalprepostdataset3$county_id, finalprepostdataset3$season), useNA = "ifany")!=1)
FALSE
```

Indicating, as I understand it, no duplicates.

But the first code would not run.

Any help would be appreciated. Posting here due to people's familiarity with `plm`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without a reproducible example.
Function `bw.GWPR` seems to stem from package `GWPR.light` and `plm` from package `plm`, both of which are not indidicated in the question.

If you `plm` statement runs successfully **without a warning**, you should be safe not to have doublicated compbinations of the observational unit (`county_id`) and time dimension (`season`) in your data.

However, to check you would leave out the `index` function in your test (or used `index` on a pdata.frame (not on variables))

```
any(table(index(<your_pdata.frame>), useNA = "ifany")!=1)
any(table(finalprepostdataset3$county_id, finalprepostdataset3$season, useNA = "ifany")!=1)
```